# postgres 9.1 full text search returning no results

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, psql, tsvector

I have searched on the web for many days by it seems the internet has never heard of my problem:

I have a postal address database table holding about 37M records for United Kingdom, which has a geospatial index and a derived full text index created like so:

```
create index on gb_locations using gin(to_tsvector('english', "Postcode" || ' ' || "Postcode_outcode" || ' ' || "Road" || ' ' || "Neighbourhood" || ' ' || "Admin2" || ' ' || "Admin3");)
```

My full text search is in the form:

```
SELECT * FROM gb_locations
WHERE
    to_tsvector('english', "Postcode" || ' ' || "Postcode_outcode" || ' ' || "Road" || ' ' || "Neighbourhood" || ' ' || "Admin2" || ' ' || "Admin3") @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'greenham road rg14')
```

The query works fine for most uk addresses, especially in the London area, but for locations furtuher afield the query returns no results.

I have verified that the record exists in the table as I can find it using a geospatial search but for a full text searches, it seems like the the database is not aware of it.

This is the explaination:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on gb_locations  (cost=52.04..56.10 rows=1 width=521)
  Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, ((((((((((("Postcode")::text || ' '::text) || ("Postcode_outcode")::text) || ' '::text) || "Road") || ' '::text) || ("Neighbourhood")::text) || ' '::text) || ("Admin2")::text) || ' '::text) || ("Admin3")::text)) @@ '''greenham'' & ''road'' & ''rg14'''::tsquery)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on text_search_index  (cost=0.00..52.04 rows=1 width=0)
        Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, ((((((((((("Postcode")::text || ' '::text) || ("Postcode_outcode")::text) || ' '::text) || "Road") || ' '::text) || ("Neighbourhood")::text) || ' '::text) || ("Admin2")::text) || ' '::text) || ("Admin3")::text)) @@ '''greenham'' & ''road'' & ''rg14'''::tsquery)
```

Any poiners would be much appreciated.

Comment: what are the values of the fields in the row that you expected would match `plainto_tsquery('english','greenham road rg14')`?

Comment: Postcode = RG147SW
Postcode_outcode=RG14
Road=Greenham Road
Neighbourhood=Newbury                                               Admin2=NULL
Admin3=West Berkshire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If certain fields can be NULL, you need to apply `coalesce(field, '')` on them in the global concatenation that gets the string to search into.

Otherwise it seems to work with the example values given in the comments:

```
select to_tsvector('english','RG147SW RG14 Greenham Road Newbury  West Berkshire')
  @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'greenham road rg14');

 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

But this one won't match (the result is NULL) and this would be the case when `Admin2` is NULL, or more generally any other field passed as is to the `||` operator.

```
   select to_tsvector('english','RG147SW RG14 Greenham Road ' || NULL || ' Newbury  West Berkshire')
      @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'greenham road rg14');

?column? 
----------

(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to what Daniel Vérité said,

a full text index must be created as follows if any of the fields are expected to be NULL:

```
create index [index name] on [table name] using gin(to_tsvector('english', coalesce("Field1",'') || ' ' || coalesce("Field2",'') || ' ' || coalesce("Field3",'') ....));
```

Furthermore the same template must be used in the query itself as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE to_tsvector('english', coalesce("Field1",'') || ' ' || coalesce("Field2",'') || ' ' || coalesce("Field3",'') ....) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', '[your search sentance/phrase]');
```